# showing the solution of heat equation decays with time

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For following PDE how can I show $||u(t,*)||_{L^2([0,l])} \le a e^{-bt}$ without solving it, where $a>0$, and $b>0$ are constants.

let, $l>0$, $S = (0,\infty)\times (0,l)$ and $u(t,x) \in  C^{1,2}(\bar S)$

\begin{align*}
u_t - u_{xx} = 0 & \; ; (t,x) \in S \\ 
u(x,0)=\frac{x(l-x)}{l^2} &\; ; 0\le x\le l\\ 
u_x(0, t) = u_x(l , t)=0&\; ; t\in (0,\infty) 
\end{align*}

The step by step hint is given [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-152-introduction-to-partial-differential-equations-fall-2011/assignments/MIT18_152F11_ProblemSet_2.pdf) but I can't follow after first step. i.e. don't know how to show 
$$\frac{d}{dt} ||u(t,*)||_{L^2([0,l])}^2 = -2||\partial_xu(t,*)||_{L^2([0,l])}^2$$

and afterwards. Thank you for  your time!!

**ADDED**::
How to show that
 1. $||u(t,*)||_{C^0([0,l])} \le \sqrt l ||u_x(t,*)||_{L^2([0,l])}$ and
 2. $ ||u(t,*)||_{L^2([0,l])}^2\le l^2 ||u_x(t,*)||_{L^2([0,l])}^2$

For (1), how can I show using fundamental theorem of Calculus and Cauchy Inequality
 $$||u(t,*)||_{C^0([0,l])} = \sup |u(t,x)|_{x\in(0,l)}\le \sqrt l \left( \int_0^l |u_x(t,x)|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Multiply both sides of the heat equation by $u$ and integrate over $[0,l]$. When integrating $u_{xx} u$ you can integrate by parts. (Why do the boundary terms vanish?)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dt} ||u(t,*)||_{L^2([0,l])}^2 =\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^l u(t,x)^2  dx=2 \int_0^l u(t,x)u_t(t,x) $$(using equation and then integration by parts with boundary conditions)
$$ 2 \int_0^l u(t,x)u_{xx}(t,x)dx= 2u(t,x)u_{x}(t,x)|_{x=0}^{x=l}-2\int_0^l u_{x}(t,x)u_{x}(t,x)dx$$
$$=-2||\partial_xu(t,*)||_{L^2([0,l])}^2$$

**Edit** Assuming that you talk about problem IV from your pdf, we note that

$$u(t, 0) = u(t , l)=0$$ (and not $u_x(t, 0) = u_x(t , l)=0$).

Let's show that
$$||u(t,*)||_{C^0([0,l])} \le \sqrt l ||u_x(t,*)||_{L^2([0,l])}.$$

We write

$$\sup_y |u(t,y)|=\sup_y |u(t,y)|=\sup_y \left|\int_0^y u_x(t,s)ds\right|\le \sup_y \int_0^y 1\cdot|u_x(t,s)|ds$$
$$\le \sup_y \sqrt{\int_0^y |u_x(t,s)|^2ds \int_0^y 1^2ds}\le\sqrt l ||u_x(t,*)||_{L^2([0,l])}.$$

From that we can conlcude that

$$\int_0^l |u(t,x)|^2dx\le ||u(t,*)||^2_{C^0([0,l])}\int_0^ldx\le  l^2 ||u_x(t,*)||^2_{L^2([0,l])}.$$

Comment: Hi, one last question, how do I show $||u||_{C^0} \le \sqrt{l}||u||_{L^2}$ and then $||u||_{L^2}^2 \le l^2 ||u_x||_{L^2}^2$. could you give hints? thank you for your time!!

Comment: * $||u||_{C^0} \le \sqrt l||u_x||_{L^2}$